# How to change this code correctly?

Tags: css, slider, slideshow

This is the first time I want to use sliding images and I've found the perfect slide on codepen but can't manage it to have only 2 or 3 images to slide. Couldn't find out, how to set the time correctly. How it's working, if I only need 2 or 3 images to slide in a time of 4 seconds on each image?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubblegum+Sans|Ubuntu');
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Bubblegum Sans', cursive;
}

slider {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

slider > * {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    animation: slide 12s infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

slide:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    animation-delay: -1s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/fm57uG/img_1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kkT5gw/img_2.jpg);
    z-index: 8;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/dVT5gw/img_3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 7;
}

slide:nth-child(4) {
    left: 0%;
    animation-delay: 8s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/m7FU8b/img_4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 6;
}

slide p {
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    color: #fff;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    5% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    25% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    30% {
        left: -100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    30.001% {
        left: -100%;
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        width: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<slider>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 1</p>
        </slide>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 2</p>
        </slide>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 3</p>
        </slide>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 4</p>
        </slide>
    </slider>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Example for 3 slides:

**HTML**

```
<slider>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 1</p>
        </slide>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 2</p>
        </slide>
        <slide>
            <p>Slide 3</p>
        </slide>
    </slider>
```

**CSS**

```
slide:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    animation-delay: -1s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/fm57uG/img_1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kkT5gw/img_2.jpg);
    z-index: 8;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 7s;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/dVT5gw/img_3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 7;
}
```

The trick is to follow the animation-delay. The first slide starts immediately (-1s), you add for the second 4 seconds so you get (3s) and for the third one you add 4s again (7s) and so on and so forth. If you need 2 slides, you delete from the HTML the third slide and remove the third child from the CSS.

Note: i only put the CSS for the slide children, you make sure you have the rest as well.

Comment: I did that just like you explained but it is not working like the original does..